# Show example where $F(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ but $F'(x_0) \neq f(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

Q: Give an example of a Riemann integrable function $f$ and a point $x_0$ so that

\begin{align*}
  F(x) &= \int_0^x f(t) \, dt \\
\end{align*}

is defined but $F'(x_0) \neq f(x_0)$.

Comment: How are you defining integrable? Depending on what your class of integrable functions is, this may or may not be doable.

Comment: Riemann Integrable. I updated main question.

Comment: This is a textbook problem from the Krantz Real Analysis textbook, Fourth Edition, section 7.3, page 164. So I presume there is a valid answer.

Comment: Hint: What happens if you change the value of f at a single point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the versions of the fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f$ is a **continuous** function from a closed interval $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ then for any $x \in (a,b)$ we have 
$$F’(x)=f(x)$$
where $F$ is defined by $F(t)=\int_a^t f(x)dx$ for $t$ in $[a,b]$. Moreover, if an integrable function differs with another function in just one point, the other function is integrable as well with equal integral. So for an example of what you ask for, just take any continuous function on $[a,b]$ and make another function out of it by simply changing the original function at one point in $(a,b)$. So an example would be $f:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with 
$$f(x)=0$$
if $x \neq \frac{1}{2}$ and $f(\frac{1}{2})=1$. Then $F’=0$ but $f$ is not 0 on $(0,1)$.

Comment: By the definition of $F$, $F'(1/2)=f(1/2)$ right?

Comment: No. The idea is that my $f$ has the same “integral function” $F$ as the zero function. The zero function is continuous so we apply FTC to it.

Comment: So $F’(1/2)=0$, since $F(t)=\int_0^t f(x)dx=\int_0^t 0 dx=0$, the second to last equality coming from the fact that $f$ and $0$ differ at only $1$ point.

Comment: My $f$ is not continuous

Comment: @M.Van Could you correct the equation formatting error in that comment before it's 5 minutes old?

Comment: @M.Van: I get it now.